# Obj-C to Swift Bridging issues: NS_ENUM -> enum

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, bridge

I'm using a Obj-C lib in Swift project with a bridging. All are OK except NS_ENUM with custom value:

Obj-C (original)

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, HTTPStatusCode) {
//    Informational 1xx
    HTTPStatusCodeContinue = 100,
    HTTPStatusCodeSwitchingProtocols = 101,
    HTTPStatusCodeProcessing = 102,
    HTTPStatusCodeCheckpoint = 103,
    ...
```

Swift (with bridging)

```
enum HTTPStatusCode : Int {

    //    Informational 1xx
    case Continue
    case SwitchingProtocols
    case Processing
    case Checkpoint
    ...
```

How NS_ENUM implementation to the bridging can convert to Swift correctly?

Comment: Actually the values Swift will generate in its bridging are lowercase --- .continue .switchingProtocols .processing .checkpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you posted here is an automatically generated Swift code, meaning that it omits implementation details.

Good news is that it still works in the same way you'd expect:

```
let x: HTTPStatusCode = .Continue
println("Continue = \(x.rawValue)")
```

prints `100`

Comment: That's fine - but what with the name of the value --- is there any way in Swift to print x's value - 'continue' ??? I could not find a way to do this --- and most Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch are exposing NS_Enum's